# ¿Por qué no se imprrime toda mi cadena de numeros?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tengo un problema con cadenas el cual es lo siguiente, primero que nada lleno de datos dos matrices, con varios ciclos anidados, después de eso quiero imprimir solo la primera matriz para checar si sí lo está almacenando pero a la hora de imprimir solo mi imprime los dos últimos números o a veces hasta los tres últimos, sin embargo en los ciclos anidados pongo un `printf` después del `scanf` para checar si los guarda o no, y en efecto si los imprime, pero el problema llega cuando quiero imprimir solo la `matriz1` por separado, ya que como dije anteriormente solo imprime unos cuantos números y no todo completo, espero me puedan ayudar con este problema ya que aún soy nuevo en esto, saludos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x=0,y=0,a=0,b=0;
    int m=0,n=0;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0;
    int matriz1[x][y];
    int matriz2[a][b];

    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la primera matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la primera matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la segunda matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la segunda matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    i=0; j=0; k=0; l=0;
    if(x==y && a==b)
    {
        for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=y;j++)
            {
                printf("\nDigite un numero en la matriz1 POSICION=%d,%d: ",i,j);
                scanf("%d",&matriz1[i][j]);
                printf("\t\t%d",matriz1[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(k=1;k<=a;k++)
        {
            for(l=1;l<=b;l++)
            {
                printf("\nDigite un numero en la matriz2 POSICION=%d: ",k,l);
                scanf("%d",&matriz2[k][l]);
                printf("\t\t%d",matriz2[k][l]);
            }
        }

    }else{
        printf("!!!ERROR CHAVO!!! LAS FILAS Y COLUMNAS DEBEN DE SER IGUALES PARA QUE SE LEVE ACABO LA SUMA");
    }

    m=0; n=0;
    for(m=1;m<=x;m++)             //aqui solo imprime unos cuantos numeros solo quiero imprimir la primera matriz para checar con la segunda no hay problema
    {
        for(n=1;n<=y;n++)
        {
            printf("\n%d",matriz2[m][n]);
        }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En general los ciclos deben empezar desde letra = 0, Hasta letra < N.
Un vector o matriz de N posiciones inicia de 0 hasta N-1

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio mucho saludos...

Answer (score 3):

Tienes errores de conceptos para trabajar con `matrices` la principal es que las matrices su posición inicial es `0`, entonces sus ciclos `for` inician en `1` por lo cuál `1` dato al menos se está perdiendo u obviando en el proceso. Además el proceso de declaración e inicialización  de variables se puede hacer directamente en el `for`. Teniendo estas dos consideraciones los ciclos `for` sería de este modelo.

```
for(int i=0;i<x;i++){ ... }
```

**Código Final**  <kbd>[Ver Demo Online](https://repl.it/Mdzj)</kbd>

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x,y,a,b=0;
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la primera matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la primera matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la segunda matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Digite las (MxN) dimensiones de la segunda matriz: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int matriz1[x][y];
    int matriz2[a][b];

    if(x==y && a==b)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
        {
          for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
          {
              printf("\nDigite un numero en la matriz1 POSICION=%d,%d: ",i,j);
              scanf("%d",&matriz1[i][j]);
               printf("\t\t%d",matriz1[i][j]);
          }
        }

        for(int k=0;k<a;k++)
        {
            for(int l=0;l<b;l++)
            {
                printf("\nDigite un numero en la matriz2 POSICION=%d: ",k,l);
                scanf("%d",&matriz2[k][l]);
                printf("\t\t%d",matriz2[k][l]);
            }
        }

    }else{
        printf("!!!ERROR CHAVO!!! LAS FILAS Y COLUMNAS DEBEN DE SER IGUALES PARA QUE SE LEVE ACABO LA SUMA");
    }

    for(int m=0;m<x;m++)             //aqui solo imprime unos cuantos numeros solo quiero imprimir la primera matriz para checar con la segunda no hay problema
    {
        for(int n=0;n<y;n++)
        {
            printf("\n%d",matriz2[m][n]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas la verdad que no entendía un por qué pasaba esto pero con esto basto para saberlo, muchas gracias por responder y tomerse el tiempo saludos...